# What is meant by the matrix of $f$ relative to a given basis of $V$?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $f$ be a linear operator on a finite dimensional vector space $V$ over a field $K$.
What is meant by the matrix of $f$ relative to a given basis of $V$?
(ask for definition)

Comment: So this is homework and the professor asked you to find out the definition without giving it in class?

Answer (score 1):

Let $(b_{1},..,b_{n})$ be a basis for $V$. The action of $f$ on each of the basis vectors $b_{i}$ may be expressed as $f(b_{i})=a_{i,1}b_{1}+...+a_{i,n}b_{n}$, again in the same basis. Note the coefficients $a_{i,j}$ where both indices range from $1,..,n$: $a_{i,j}$ is the projection of $f(b_{i})$ onto basis vector $j$. If we construct the matrix $M=[\{a_{i,j}\}_{1\leq i,j\leq n}]$ the product of $M x=f(x)$ where $x$ is a vector in $V$ is easy to compute if $x$ is presented using the given basis.